# XML Attribute Starts With, in JScript, with IE

Tags: javascript, xml, internet-explorer, xpath

In JavaScript running in an .aspx page, in Internet Explorer 8, I have the following XML in xDataSpc:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetListItemsResponse xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
      <GetListItemsResult>
        <listitems xmlns:s="uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882" xmlns:dt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882" xmlns:rs="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset" xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema">
          <rs:data ItemCount="1163">
            <z:row SpcID="1.00000000000000" ows_SpaceNum="206-1"/>
            <z:row SpcID="3.00000000000000" ows_SpaceNum="206-11"/>
            <z:row SpcID="4.00000000000000" ows_SpaceNum="206-2"/>
            <z:row SpcID="5.00000000000000" ows_SpaceNum="206-3"/>
            <z:row SpcID="184.000000000000" ows_SpaceNum="2037"/>
            <z:row SpcID="185.000000000000" ows_SpaceNum="2038"/>
            . . .
```

I have a number, for which I want to find the row. The # is a Space ID, as an integer.

So, if I have a '3,' I want to get the 2nd row.

I have tried all these:

```
xDataSpc.responseXML.selectSingleNode("//rs:data/z:row[@SpcID='3.00000000000000']") 
xDataSpc.responseXML.selectSingleNode("//rs:data/z:row[starts-with( @SpcID,  '3.']")
xDataSpc.responseXML.selectSingleNode("//rs:data/z:row[starts-with('@SpcID', '3.']")
xDataSpc.responseXML.selectSingleNode("//rs:data/z:row[@SpcID^='3.']")
```

and more. I simply cannot find a way to specify the beginning characters of `SpcID.`  The first entry, specifying the ***whole*** attribute value functions, it returns the row I am after.

Everything else gives me “Unknown function.”

Answer (score 1):

There is a missing bracket in your second attempt:

```
xDataSpc.responseXML.selectSingleNode("//rs:data/z:row[starts-with( @SpcID,  '3.']")
```

should be:

```
xDataSpc.responseXML.selectSingleNode("//rs:data/z:row[starts-with( @SpcID,  '3.')]")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
var doc = xDataSpc.responseXML;
doc.setProperty('SelectionLanguage', 'XPath');
```

then you can use your `doc.selectSingleNode("//rs:data/z:row[starts-with( @SpcID,  '3.']")` without problems. The default selection language with MSXML 3 is not the XPath 1.0 standard defined by the W3C but an older draft that these days only Microsoft supports.

Comment: What is the syntax to find this row with the IE default?

Comment: Also, these two statements: They set the property of xDataSpc, or set properties on a copy of responseXML?

If the former, would

    xDataSpc.responseXML.setProperty('SelectionLanguage', 'XPath');

work as well?

Comment: If you want to type `xDataSpc.responseXML.setProperty('SelectionLanguage', 'XPath');` you can of course do that, the assigment to a variable was just an attempt to save on typing `xDataSpc.responseXML.selectSingleNode` each line. As for the syntax with the MSXML default, sorry, I don't know details of that language, XPath 1.0 is a standard since 1999 and I have not used the IE specific selection language since then, I don't think it is anywhere documented these days.

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me, Martin. 

I tried `xDataSpc.responseXML.setProperty("SelectionLanguage", "XPath"),` followed by `xDataSpc.responseXML.selectSingleNode("//rs:data/z:row[starts-with(@SpcID, '3.']").` 

The result is an error: "Reference to undeclared namespace prefix: 'rs'."

Comment: You need to define the namespaces with another property I am afraid: `xDataSpc.responseXML.setProperty("SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:rs='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset' xmlns:z='#RowsetSchema'");`.